# How can I create a new table in SQL where some rows are exact matches and some are not?

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a few tables as follows:

Users table:

```
| id | name        | email       |
+----+-------------+-------------+
| 1  | David       | Dave@example.com
| 2  | Bill        | Dave@example.com
| 3  | David       | Dave@example.com
```

Favorites table:

```
| userid | favoriteanimal |
+--------+----------------+
| 1      | Hippo          | 
| 2      | Dog            |
| 3      | Hippo          |
```

Activity table:

```
| userid | firstday  | lastday   |  daysused |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3      | 7/31/2019 | 8/2/2019  | 2         |
| 1      | 8/3/2019  | 8/20/2019 | 4         |
| 2      | 7/31/2019 | 8/20/2019 | 15        |
```

I want to create a new table in my database that collapses the current tables in a few different ways: Email, Name, and Favorite animal should match. If the all match and we have multiple rows look at the activity table, if the first day for one user is the next day after the same user's last day, we should combine those users so that we now have a new row with the firstday being the earliest day, userid being the id from the earliest day user, and lastday being the latest last day. Days used should add up the daysused from userids.

The results I'm expecting should look like below:

```
| userid | firstday  | lastday   | daysused | favoriteanimal |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------------+
| 2      | 7/31/2019 | 8/20/2019 | 15       | Hippo          |
| 3      | 7/31/2019 | 8/20/2019 | 6        | Dog            |
```

I have the following fiddle that I am playing around with, but I have been unsuccessful so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/09b76/11

Comment: You say userid, name, and favorite animal should match. I think I get what you mean, but userid 1 and userid 3 don't match. What you're saying is that just because they got a different userid, they still are the same person, though, is that correct? Wouldn't e-mail address be a better mechanism to use for that than userid?

Comment: Oops you are right that's what I meant to say, we want to use the userid from the user with the earliest firstday when the emails match! I will update. This problem is making my brain mush for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select u.id as userid, u.name, u.email, f.favoriteanimal,
    a.firstday, a.lastday, a.daysused,
        case when datediff(day,
                 lag(a.lastday) over (
                     partition by u.name, u.email, f.favoriteanimal
                     order by a.firstday, a.lastday),
                 a.firstday
             ) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as gap
    from users as u
          inner join activity as a on u.id = a.userid
          inner join favorites as f on f.userid = u.id
), concatenated as (
    select *,
        sum(gap) over (partition by name, email, favoriteanimal order by firstday, lastday) as grp
    from data
), agg as (
    select
        userid, favoriteanimal,
        row_number()  over (partition by name, email, favoriteanimal, grp order by firstday) as rn,
        min(firstday) over (partition by name, email, favoriteanimal, grp) as firstday,
        max(lastday)  over (partition by name, email, favoriteanimal, grp) as lastday,
        sum(daysused) over (partition by name, email, favoriteanimal, grp) as daysused
    from concatenated
)
select userid, firstday, lastday, daysused, favoriteanimal
from agg where rn = 1;
```

When I introduced a wider gap between users 1 and 3 it returns separate rows. Here's an example: https://rextester.com/MONL73656

Comment: Awesome thanks! That is a wonderful response. The only issue I have with it is it doesn't work with 3 or more entries, but I'm sure if I were to continue down this path I would be able to use recursion.

Comment: @emmajean Thanks. I just tried it out on three back-to-back date ranges and it worked for me. If you add some more test data I can take a look again.

Comment: I just found my mistake. I made an entry that was in between the others and that screwed it up you way works!

Answer (score 1):

Please check below query for your answer.

```
SELECT
MIN(a.userid) USERID,
u.name,
u.email,
f.favoriteanimal,
MIN(a.firstday) FirstDay,
MAX(a.lastday) LastDay,
SUM(a.daysused) daysused,
count(a.userid) usercnt
FROM
 users u
 INNER JOIN activity a ON u.id = a.userid
 INNER JOIN favorites f ON f.userid = u.id
GROUP BY u.name,
u.email,
f.favoriteanimal
```

Comment: This seems to miss the requirement that later activity rows are only valid if they start the day after the prior activity row ended... but it's probably still the best answer. The heuristic still very closely matches the requirements, and I suspect if they went back to the stakeholders for the issue, they would want all of those rows anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, the day after portion is really important in this case, but this answer definitely gets me further than I have gotten on my own.

Answer (score 0):

So the question changed while I was still writing this get much simpler and allow matching only on e-mail. Matching only on e-mail allows us to *greatly* simplify this down a `GROUP BY` query. But since I didn't want to throw away the work:

```
SELECT first.id as userid, first.firstday, 
    coalesce(second.lastday, first.lastday) lastday,
    coalesce(second.daysused + first.daysused, first.daysused) daysused,
    base.favoriteanimal
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT u.name, u.email, f.favoriteanimal
    FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN Favorites f on f.userid = u.id
) base
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 u.id, a.firstday, a.lastday, a.daysused
    FROM Users u 
    INNER JOIN Favorites f on f.userid = u.id
    INNER JOIN Activity a on a.userid = u.id
    WHERE u.name = base.Name and u.email = base.email and f.favoriteanimal = base.favoriteanimal
    ORDER BY a.firstday
) first
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 a.lastday, a.daysused
    FROM Users u 
    INNER JOIN Favorites f on f.userid = u.id
    INNER JOIN Activity a on a.userid = u.id
    WHERE u.name = base.Name and u.email = base.email and f.favoriteanimal = base.favoriteanimal 
        and u.id <> first.id and a.FirstDay = DateAdd(day, 1, first.LastDay)
) second
```

If you want to get real fancy, you can get this into a recursive CTE, that keeps running to find more and more `second` result sets, so a user could have many stops/starts.

Comment: Yeah, in my real case I will need to add recursion as there will be many stops/starts. This is an "oversimplified" example of what I am really doing. I appreciate your thorough and creative solution!